# Auto positioning/aligning floating divs with different div sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 3 divs inside a main div as marked up in the HTML /CSS code below, when the page renders, the second div is twice as large as the first and last. When the page renders, because the second div is twice the size of the first and last, this causes the last div to display below the second, leaving a gap inbetween. What I want is that the third div occupies that gap that:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Liquid Divs</title>
<style>

#splash {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.box {
    width: 196px;
    height: 196px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    float: left;
}

.box2 {
    width: 392px;
    height: 392px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    float: left;
}

.clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="splash">

        <div class="box">
        </div>

        <div class="box2">
        </div>

        <div class="box">
        </div>

        <div class="clear-fix">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can this be done with CSS or does anyone know a method to accomplish this with javascript? It will be helpful to figure this out.

Comment: do you want 3rd box to be below the first one or after the 2 one?

Comment: down-voted for not clarifying what was required (javascript or CSS solution) and not responding back. Remember that people spend time and resources to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you plan on including more elements in `#splash` you are after the jQuery plugin masonry

here is a soltion demo for the extension problem

### http://jsfiddle.net/kxMYS/

```
$( function() {

    $('#splash').masonry({
        itemSelector: 'div'
    });

});
```

**however**

if you only want a solution to you're exact given problem

just change your css for `.box2` to `float:left;`

### http://jsfiddle.net/kxMYS/1/

Comment: Seriously? TRY READING WHAT I PUT "if you plan on including more elements" use jquery if you only want a solution to you're exact given problem just change your css for .box2 to float:left; ..... seriously annoys me when people on SO don't read the entire post and come to conclusions, i included the jquery method as an extra i gave more detail and more info as well as his direct solution, go sleep you obviously need it.

Comment: I think what I was looking for is masonry

Comment: @Teemu .... hardy hardy ha and Patrick thankyou for proving that i helped, if you need any more assistance don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1):

Switch up your box2 to float right

```
.box2 {
    width: 392px;
    height: 392px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    float: right;
}
```

Tested and it works placing the 3rd box beneath the first

Answer (score 0):

Wrap 1st and 3rd boxes in left-container and the big box in right-container
Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/wcQ3L/1/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Liquid Divs</title>

<style>
#splash {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#left-container{
    float: left;
}
.box {
    width: 196px;
    height: 196px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;    
}

.box2 {
    width: 392px;
    height: 392px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    float: left;
}

.clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="splash">

        <div id="left-container">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right-container">
        <div class="box2">
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="clear-fix">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```